# Textbox with rounded corners using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a predefined textbox in a PowerPoint slide, I need to make its corners rounded. Is there any way I can do this using VBA?

Comment: I don't think you can round the corners of a VBA textbox, but you could [put it in a rounded rectangle (Excel example)](http://excelusergroup.org/forums/t/2450.aspx). Would this work for you?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion Richard, unfortunately, this will not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example assumes that the shape you're after is the third shape on slide 1.  Adjust accordingly:

```
Sub Test()
Dim oSh As Shape
Set oSh = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(3)
With oSh
    .AutoShapeType = msoShapeRoundedRectangle
    .Adjustments(1) = 0.25
End With
End Sub
```

It converts the textbox to a rounded rectangle then sets the corners to be rounded.  As far as I know, you cannot round the corners of a regular text box.

Comment: Thanks Steve, you have sloved my problem