# Getting the numerical value of a shape's corner radius? (ex: rectangle with rounded corners)

Tags: vba, powerpoint

In **VBA**, I am able to get a shape's x, y, width and height values by doing the following:

```
Debug.Print , , "x:"; Round(itm.Left), "y:"; Round(itm.Top)
Debug.Print , , "width:"; Round(itm.Width), "height:"; Round(itm.Height)
```

I want to find the same shape's **corner radius**, for example - the corner radius of a rectangle with rounded corners. Any idea how this can be done?
Also, the shape is in powerpoint.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I dont know much about Powerpoint, but some quick googling shows this: `itm.Adjustments(1) `

Comment: Hey @braX Can you think of a way to maybe calculate the corner radius using the 4 values we already know - x, y, width, height?

Comment: Not really, the only assumption you can make is that the radius is less than half of width and less than half of the height.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131654/textbox-with-rounded-corners-using-vba

Comment: The adjustment value is fraction of the minimum dimension (height/width) of the shape, so you can use that information to calculate the radius.